# Ajax does not work with MVC custom Routing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been going through so many forums to get solution but all in vain.
My problem is :

I have an action in my home controller named CallUser. I am calling this via ajax.

My URL looks like mydomain.com/Home/CallUser

I want my URL like mydomain.com/CallUser

I do not want to have "/Home" in accessing any of the action

So I added custom routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Custom", 
                    "{action}/{id}", 
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Ajax call:

```
function CallUser()
{

    var mobNum = $('#userMobileNo').val();   
    var isValidNumber=validatePhone(mobNum);
    if(isValidNumber)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Home/CallUser",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ destinationNumber: mobNum }),
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {


            },
            error: function (err) {               

            },
            failure: function(err)
            {              

            }
        });
    }
    else
    {       

    }
}
```

Call to Blog action in home controller

```
@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Blog", "Home")
```

Comment: You have not specified `controller` in `"{action}/{id}",` So you need to  remove `Home` from url. Use `"../CallUser",` instead of `"../Home/CallUser",`

Comment: @Satpal he want to omit the controller name

Comment: @Optimus, then why OP is using `Home` in URL `"../Home/CallUser",`

Comment: Routing is based around controllers and actions (and optionally areas and other custom fields). You could change the mapping of everything to use a single controller, so that would become redundant, but that is wrong on so many levels. How about using another, better named, controller like `UserController` so the URL becomes `User/CallUser` or `User/Call`?

Comment: You call your URL without the two dots (..) and your custom route has action/id whereas your js shows controller/action

Answer (score 1):

Rather than break the standard MVC pattern, just because of a dislike of the URL, just create a `UserController` and have a `Call` action so the URL becomes the readable:

```
"../User/Call"
```

This then lends itself to URLs like:

```
"../User/Hangup"
"../User/GiveAbuse"
"../User/Ignore"
"../User/WhyDontTheyEverCall"
```

Controllers are meant to encompass one part of the problem domain (in this case all actions to do with users), so why fight the MVC way of doing it :)

Comment: TrueBlueAussie: The problem still remains the same with your solution. Because of the custom URL I have provided system is skipping controller name and unable to find my action. For your solution to work I have to remove my custom routing which will affect my other actions such as blog

Comment: @user3678961: Please provide examples of all your URLs, You can have multiple routings in place. You just need to make sure each has enough information to make the mappings unique for your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way by which you can do your desire ajax call.

> 1.change your passed ajax url to **url: "../CallUser"**

or

> You need to add controller name to created route like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Custom", 
                 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Your second option would not get rid of the need for `Home` in the URL as *the controller is only optional when no action is specified either*.

Comment: I had already tried way one, and it did not work. And for your second way, I agree with TrueBlueAussie. I would still be seeing '/Home' in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as your first route (before the default one)

```
routes.MapRoute("CallUser", 
                "CallUser/{destinationNumber}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "CallUser"}
                );

routes.MapRoute("Blog", 
                //You may have to change parameter name based on your action signature 
                "Blog/{destinationNumber}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Blog"}
                );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Your action has to have the following signature (parameter name is important!):

```
public ActionResult CallUser(string destinationNumber)
{
}
```

Ajax call:

```
function CallUser()
{

var mobNum = $('#userMobileNo').val();   
var isValidNumber=validatePhone(mobNum);
if(isValidNumber)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("CallUser","Home")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ destinationNumber: mobNum }),
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {


        },
        error: function (err) {               

        },
        failure: function(err)
        {              

        }
    });
}
else
{       

}
}
```

Comment: Including this route with mine gives me run time error. Replacing my route affects other action of mine. For instance I have an Action Blog. When I click on blog I see url as mydomain.com/home/blog.

Comment: First of all it is supposed to replace your route. Second you should still have the default route registration(it should be the last one). See the updated answer

Comment: I don't really understand, do you want all you routes to omit the controller name and not just the CallUser?

Comment: Yes I want all my routes to omit controller name.

Comment: If you want all your routes to omit controller name you will have to specify a separate rote for each and every action(It will be similar to the custom rote that I have in my answer but with different controller and action names)

Comment: Other than that your only solution could be implementing all your actions in one controller which is a BAD

Comment: I have all my actions in one controller only. I have called my blog action from html. and I got mu URL as expected. mydomain.com/blog. Please check my update.

Comment: You may have some serious issues with your application architecture because all the actions in one controller is very suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using attribute routing. I like to see the routes in my face while I am in the controllers.

You can prefix the controller and specify a route above each method.

```
[RoutePrefix("books-api/loans")]
public class LoansController : ApiController
{
    private IBookRepository _bookRepository;
    public LoansController(IBookRepository bookRepository)
    {
        _bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Loan loan)
    {
        _bookRepository.Loan(loan);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

You do need to enable it.

This is a Web API article but I believe it applies to MVC controllers as well:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: MVC3 does not support :(

Comment: sorry about that then